# Getting attribute and adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I want add class for a child element like in example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" title="forum">
            <i class="fa"></i>
            Forum
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var title = $(".menu-item a").attr('title');

$(".menu-item a i").addClass(
    function( title ) {
      return "fa-" + title;
    });
});
```

I don't know how repair this JavaScript.

Comment: Are you trying to add a class to the `<i>` tag, or replace all the classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something more like this :

```
$(".menu-item a").each(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');

    $(this).find("i").addClass("fa-" + title);
});
```

This will loop through each `a` and get its own title. It will then add the class to his descendant.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var title = $(".menu-item a").attr('title');
$(".menu-item a i").addClass("fa-"+title);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/CTt38/

Answer (score 0):

this will go through each `i` in `.menu-item` then add the title attribute of the parent to the class...

```
$('.menu-item i').addClass(function () {
  return 'fa-' + this.parentNode.title;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/peyofira/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var title = "fa-" + $(".menu-item a").attr('title');
$(".menu-item i").addClass(title);
});
```